# ButtonType ButtonData.OK CSS JavaFX Alert

Tags: css, button, javafx, dialog, alert

I'm trying to style ma Alert in JavaFX. My buttons in general are alright. This is what I have in my Java Class:

```
alert.getDialogPane().getStylesheets().add("/gui/style.css");
ButtonType importButtonType = new ButtonType("Importeer", ButtonData.OK_DONE);
ButtonType cancelButtonType = new ButtonType("Annuleer", ButtonData.CANCEL_CLOSE);
alert.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().setAll(importButtonType, cancelButtonType);
```

And this is what I have in my CSS :

```
.dialog-pane .button {
 -fx-font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; 
-fx-font-size: 14;
-fx-text-fill: #55595c;
-fx-background-color: #d0d0d0;
}
```

But I want to style my ButtonType with the ButtonData.OK_DONE in a different style. Any Ideas how?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I found the solution by myself. 
If someone is still interested :

```
Button okBtn = (Button) alert.getDialogPane().lookupButton(alert.getButtonTypes().get(index_of_the_OK_button));
okBtn.getStyleClass().add(your_custom_class);
```

with your custom class in your css file, it should work :)

Answer (score 0):

To change the default button used in dialog/alerts, you can add the following to your css file.

```
.root { -fx-default-button: red; }
```

Another option would be to add the following:

```
.button:default { -fx-base: red; }
```